# How to change line color between points dynamically?

Tags: highcharts

How can I have a line graph where the segment's color between two consecutive points p1 and p2 is defined by p2 data attribute "lineColor" for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'multicolor series' plugin: http://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/

Answer (score 3):

Using `zone` and `zoneAxis` will help you for that. [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/1fncxsyz/1/)

Comment: but zones require some definite correlation between the values, what if there is no such correlation? can we achieve the same without using zones, some what like we can define marker for each point? the use case is for example if at one place line at 0 value should be red but for the next time may be blue?

Comment: @SaifUllah, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317950/3200799) that I made in another question.