# How to dynamically change line color based on value being lower than previous in highcharts

Tags: mysql, highcharts

I am trying to build a line chart using highchart.js that uses the color green and black. The data is pulled from an SQL database and if the value is higher than the previous value it is green. If the value is less than the previous value than the color is black.

I am new at this and have been searching and searching but the only things I find is using zones to change the colors.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this example, it should help you :

```
series: [{
  name: 'Random data',
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: (function() {
    // generate an array of random data
    var time = (new Date()).getTime(),
      i,
      yValue;

    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
      yValue = Math.random();

      if (i > -19 && yValue > data[data.length - 1].y) { // Green point
        zones.push({
          color: "#5f9",
          value: time + i * 1000,
        });
      } else if (i > -19 && yValue <= data[data.length - 1].y) { // black point
        zones.push({
          color: "#000",
          value: time + i * 1000,
        });
      } else { // first point alway green
        zones.push({
          color: "#5f9",
          value: time + i * 1000,
        });
      }
      data.push({
        x: time + i * 1000,
        y: yValue
      });
    }
    return data;
  }()),
  zoneAxis: "x",
  zones: zones
}]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4rmxyb6/1/)

Comment: Thanks so much. This is definitely what I was looking for. Could you also explain to me what this is doing and how it is going about it? Also if I changed the colors the last dot always stays green and not sure how I change this. Thanks!